# Angular throwing NullInjection error only on production

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(r)[Uw]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[Uw]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Uw!
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(r)[Uw]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[Uw]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Uw!
```

In `app.module.ts`:-

```
providers: [
    PageService,
    SortService,
    FilterService,
    GroupService,
    EditService,
    ToolbarService,
    SelectionService,
    PdfExportService,
    ExcelExportService,
    ConfigService,
    FreezeService,
    ParticipantsService,
  ],
```

All services are present in app.module.ts.
Importing httpClientModule,HttpModule.

Working fine on localhost, only in production it throws error.

Comment: what's Uw in your scope? which is the `class`/`function` throwing the error?

Comment: No provider for Uw???  is there any service or dependency named UW

Comment: There is nothing as Uw in our project. We don't know where it is coming from.

Comment: @SriVenkataPavanKumarMHS There isn't any server or dependency by that name. Infact we are using one service called **Sync Fusion** [https://www.syncfusion.com/angular-ui-components]. We taught this might be causing the error but it's not.

Comment: @FrontTheMachine There's no such **class / function**

Comment: try searching for Uw in your codebase and see even if by mistake it has been written in an of the files